# react-navigation: have the same state as a previous route, but act as a push?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Say I have **Screen 1** and **Screen 2**. I navigate from **Screen 1** to **Screen 2** by pushing. So **Screen 1** is still there, and its state is unchanged. But, I want to be able to navigate to a third screen, **Screen 3**, that has EXACTLY the same state as **Screen 1** (a copy), but acts like a **push**.

Pushing from **Screen 1** to **Screen 2** gives me a card transition, but I basically want to push from **Screen 2** to **Screen 3** (another card transition), but have **Screen 3** to have the same state as **Screen 1**, like scrolling is the same, data is the same, etc.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, I cannot upload any gifs for clarification because many of them are too large. An example would be from the Reddit app: moving from the tabular view to viewing a post (where the tab view disappears), but then when you click on the subreddit's name, it takes you (with a push animation) to another tab view, but it's the same one.

**EDIT 2:** [Here is a link of a screen recording of what I want.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FjQKNgl2tafmvTlHZmDRtFrgIebiGKo1/view?usp=sharing)

1. So the first screen shows me scrolling down to a certain area. (tabular view) - `Screen 1`
2. Then there's a card navigation to a "View Post Screen", where you can see comments, etc. (no tabs) - `Screen 2`
3. Then I clicked on r/aww, which navigates with a card transition to the subreddit page. (tabular view) - `Screen 3`
4. The tab for `Screen 3` is scrolled to the same place as I scrolled in `Screen 1`. This is what I meant by "same state".

Pushing another route of the same name doesn't work, because everything is set back to default, and would be bad for user experience. Going back wouldn't work because it would show a card "go back" transition from `Screen 2` to `Screen 3` - a card "push" transition is more natural.

Comment: This sounds like an unintuitive control flow. Is it possible to _pop_ back to Screen 1, but substitute the _push_ animation for the default pop animation?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I'm not really sure how. Check my edit for an example if you need clarification?

Comment: You could try passing the state of Screen1 as navigation props/params. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372616/set-initial-state-from-navigation-props

Comment: @NRitH that also would not work, because if I pop back to Screen 1, then I cannot go back from Screen 3 to Screen 2 to Screen 1.

Comment: Your video example doesn't have two screens that are exactly the same though, so I'm confused about that. Why do you want screen three (single subreddit view?) scrolled to the same place as screen one (list of subreddits)?

Comment: Also it doesn't appear screen 3 is scrolled to the same place as screen 1 in that example. I'm very confused. Anyways you could absolutely preserve scroll state through navigation prams or through more advanced state management like redux

Comment: @NoahAllen so around the 4sec mark shows me scrolling down to a certain point on the list of subreddits on `Screen 1`. At the very end, when a new screen, `Screen 3`, is pushed, around 13sec mark, it shows the list of subreddits, scrolled to the same point as it was at the 4sec mark. Does this make more sense?

Comment: This is how the video appears to go: View 1 is list of subreddits, on a tab. View 2 you tap the home tab. View 3, you tap a post so it is view post. View 4, you tab the subreddit, and you view a subreddit. View 5, you switch back to the list of subreddits tab (screen 1). The reason I'm confused is that I'm not sure how what you want to do is related to that. Specifically, it makes sense that View 1 and View 5 have the same state - it's the same screen on the tab and nothing changed. But in you say you want to do some kind of copy??

Answer (score 1):

In `react-navigation` you can navigate to unlimited - in theory - of same screen. If you wish to change the contents of the screen you can use navigation parameters. You can think instagram app for example.

User(me) -> Followers -> User(Alice) -> Followers -> User(Bob) -> Followers -> User(John)

```
const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Followers: { screen: Followers },
  User: { screen: Profile },
});

/...
this.props.navigation.navigate('User', { user: 'me' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('Followers', { user: 'me' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('User', { user: 'Alice' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('Followers', { user: 'Alice' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('User', { user: 'Bob' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('Followers', { user: 'Bob' });
this.props.navigation.navigate('User', { user: 'John' });
```

Comment: There's some confusion as to what I'm asking about. I posted a google drive link to a screen recording. I hope this helps understand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your use case scenario is that you want to preserve the styling and structure of a component across different screens. I have two takeaways here:

- If the two screens (`Screen1` and `Screen3`) are *exactly* the same, then why would you want a duplicate in the first place? Why not show the `Screen1` again to keep your stack size small? In your example: User is on `Screen1` which is subreddit's homepage. Then they click on a post link which takes them to `Screen2`. Again, when user clicks on the link to subreddit's homepage, they are not opening a *new screen*, they are simply *going back* to the original `Screen1`.
- If there are slight differences between the two screens, your could simply employ component re-use. Like, if there are two subreddits `r/android` and `r/reactnative`, you'll have a single component for both of them: `<SubRedditComponent>` but their data and styling would be different.

Comment: There's some confusion as to what I'm asking about. I posted a google drive link to a screen recording. I hope this helps understand my problem?